# How to generate a PEM file with Openssl using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 cipher

Tags: apache, ssl, encryption

I been trying to create a key and certificate for apache web server than contains an https site. I been using Openssl (version 1.0.1f,g,h,i,q,t), and I can't create a certificate using cipher suite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256.

I use the folliwing code to setting up the cipher list:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'kEECDH+ECDSA kEDH +RSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !DES !RC2 !RC4 !EXP !DSS !IDEA !SRP !kECDH !MD5 !SEED !PSK !CAMELLIA'
```

And it's the result:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

After that I been using the following commands to generate the certificate:

```
Step 1
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -outform PEM -out my-site.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

Step 2
openssl req -new -sha256 -key my-site.pem -out my-site.csr

Step 3
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 1825 -in my-site.csr -signkey my-site.pem -out my-site.crt
```

When I install all files on apache, restart the server, and then chek out the results using Mozilla, I get the following result:

**Encrypted connection(TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)**

I'm confused about this because I have made many tests and read lots of information without getting a different result.

I appreciate any guidance!!

Comment: Based on Steffen's answer, just add on the host site file the following instruction and achieve the result I was looking for: SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AE‌​S128-GCM-SHA256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cipher used by the server has not much to do with the certificate. In the case of ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 you only need a normal RSA certificate which you have generated. The other parts of the cipher describe the key exchange (ECDHE), algorithm for symmetric encryption and HMAC (AES128-GCM-SHA256). These parts depend on the server configuration and on the capabilities of the client but not on the certificate.

Comment: Do you know how to enable it in apache 2.4 ? it is enabled in the configuration but the server dont take it, I have exactly the same apache config files on another server and this cipher work, I need it for http2

Comment: @neoteknic: Please don't ask new questions in a comment. Apart from that there are lots of question here about cipher settings which don't work, usually because they are not supported by the library used or because there is a different config file with different settings which take precedence.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich are you sure that the certificate is not involved in the cipher used by the server ? What if the certificate doesn't contain an RSA key ? (For example ECDHE_ECDSA). In my opinion the certificate matters at least for the key exchange algorithm to be selected: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/what-key-exchange-mechanism-should-be-used-in-tls

Comment: @Bemipefe: Please read carefully. I did not claim that the certificate is not involved but that cipher selection *"has __not much__ to do"* with the certificate. I've even explained that for this specific cipher *"you only need a normal __RSA__ certificate"*. And, in case of ECDHE (or DHE) the certificate does not matter at all for the key exchange - both work with ECDSA and RSA certificates. Only in case of RSA key exchange the type of certificates matter since this key exchange can only be done with RSA certificates. Note that ECDHE_ECDSA is no key exchange, but ECDHE is.